# Exception safe move operator

Tags: c++, move

I generally (try to) write exception safe copy assignment operators using the copy-swap idiom, and I was wondering if I should be concerned about exceptions when writing the move assignement operators.
Here is an example of a copy assignement operator:

```
template<class T>
CLArray<T>&
CLArray<T>::operator=( const CLArray& rhs )
{
    CLArray tmp( rhs );
    std::swap( size_, tmp.size_ );
    std::swap( data_, tmp.data_ );
    return *this;
}
```

But what about the move assignement ? I mean, if an exception is thrown somewhere else in the code during THIS move operation, I will lose the state of both objects right ? So I would have to create a local copy first and then delete everything but the newly created `CLArray` ...

```
template <class T>
CLArray<T>&
CLArray<T>::operator=( CLArray<T>&& rhs )
{
    size_ = rhs.size_;
    data_ = std::move( rhs.data_ );
    return *this;
}
```

Please note that `data_` is a std::vector, and thanks for the answers !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, it can be difficult or impossible to provide exception guarantees if a move constructor might throw.

I would suggest doing as the standard library does: document that certain operations only have exception guarantees (or, in some cases, are only permitted) if move-construction of `T` doesn't throw. Ensuring the guarantee by copying the object destroys the benefit of move-assignment for all types, not just the (very rare) ones that might throw.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I totally get why creating a copy would be stupid for a move assignement.

Answer (score 3):

Anyway you should add a `swap` member function and leverage the (copy / move) constructors in the (copy / move) assignment operators. (And put the operations that can't throw after those that might.)

Example (here inline in the class for brevity):

```
template<typename T>
class CLArray {
public:
    void swap( CLArray& other )
    {
        std::swap( data_, other.data_ );
        std::swap( size_, other.size_ );
    }

    CLArray( const CLArray& other )
        : data_( other.data_ ), size_( other.size_ )
    {
    }

    CLArray& operator=( const CLArray& rhs )
    {
        CLArray( rhs ).swap( *this );
        return *this;
    }

    CLArray( CLArray&& other )
        : data_( std::move( other.data_ ) )
    {
        size_ = other.size_;
        other.size_ = 0;
    }

    CLArray& operator=( CLArray&& rhs )
    {
        CLArray( std::move( rhs ) ).swap( *this );
        return *this;
    }

    // ...

private:
    std::vector<T> data_;
    std::size_t    size_;
};
```

See [C9 Lectures: Stephan T. Lavavej - Standard Template Library (STL), 9 of n (rvalue references)](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Standard-Template-Library-STL-/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Standard-Template-Library-STL-9-of-n) (video and STL's remarks and code in the comments).

You may also want to read Dave Abrahams's articles [Your Next Assignment…](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/09/your-next-assignment/) and [Exceptionally Moving!](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/10/exceptionally-moving/).